# How to combine small vuejs app with big SPA also vuejs app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a main SPA app that is compiled and distributed to the users. I would like to let developers create extensions for this SPA. Basically, I would like to give them the ability to create their own views and do what they want within these views.

I see them setting up their own project for the extension they want to create. They create a normal vuejs app and after they compile it they are able to plug it to the SPA I have developed.

Is this possible and what kind of javascript magic would be needed for this to happen?

Anyone that has done this that can share some details and pointers?

Comment: why not ask your developers?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a private package either on `npm` (which costs money) or you could do it on `verdaccio` (for free) another option is simply to have the repo as a dependency in the package JSON like this:
`"myPackage": ""git+https://github.com/myusername/myRepo.git"`
Of course the exact URL (http or https) would depend on your repo.